# Mysql Multiplication Operation

Tags: mysql, multiplication

I have got a float fild with value = 2.05 and when I do field*1000 the result is
2049.999952316284
Why isn´t the result 2050.0? .

Thanks

Comment: If you need it exact then use `decimal` in instead of a `float`

Answer (score 1):

Presumably because the field is not stored as 2.05 but rather 2.04999. What happens if you increase the resolution of the field, ie store it as 2.0500?

This problem is due to computers' inability to store some real numbers accurately.

Incidentally, if the value is supposed to be a currency value, store it as numeric (12,2) and then there won't be any floating point errors.